# Under what conditions is $R \cong I \times R/I$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring and $I$ be an ideal of $R$. Under what conditions, do we have $R \cong I \times (R/I)$. I think we cannot exhibit an explicit isomorphism in this case. Any hint would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: do you just want $R$ to be isomorphic to $I\times (R/I)$ as a group? note that $I$ is not a (unital) ring in general

Comment: if you demand that $I$ be a unital ring, then this means $I$ is principal and generated by an idempotent element of $R$. on the other hand, any ideal generated by a central idempotent of $R$ will satisfy the condition you desire.

Comment: If $I$ is an ideal then $I$ must be a ring.

Comment: okay, so are rings not necessarily unital for you? if so I would put this information in your post as it is nowadays a bit more common to assume rings are unital

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom The original problem that I wanted to solve was: If $0 \to R \to_i M \to_j N \to 0$ is an exact sequence and $p : N \to M$ is homomorphism such that $jp = \text{id}_N$ then $M \cong R \times N$. Since $R \cong \text{im} \, i = \text{ker} \, j$ and $M / \text{ker} \, j \cong N$ thus the assertion follows if one proves the statement in my question.

Comment: So you're talking about $R$ modules isomorphism, not necessarily rings.

Comment: @rschwieb I am just talking about exact sequence of rings.

Comment: @MuhammadAtifZaheer You mean, in your original problem, $M$ and $N$ stand for rings? Those are pretty suggestive of modules.

Comment: @rschwieb Yeah, they are rings.

Comment: ok... if you say so!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming $R$ has an identity.

You say you think you're talking about a sequence in the category of rings, not modules.  It is not hard at all to exhibit ring isomorphisms $R\cong I\times R/I$. For example, given a central idempotent $e$, you have $R= eRe\times (1-e)R(1-e)$ and it's easy to see $R/eRe\cong (1-e)R(1-e)$.

But if, as I suspect, the problem you quoted as being what "you wanted to solve" is about modules, the same thing holds: given any idempotent element $e$ of $R$, $R=eR\oplus (1-e)R$ and it's easy to show $R/eR\cong (1-e)R$ as modules.

In both cases, the obvious map is the right isomorphism: $r\mapsto (er, r +eR)$